Datasource access Superset
I have Superset version 2.1.0
I need to give access to group of people on particular dashboard
I have an issue while giving access to gamma role on particular dataset (because there is no opportunity to give access direct on dashboard).
Sometimes when I give access on datasource ,gamma user can see created charts/dashboards where this dataset was used as source and this situation is what I need .
But when I give access on another dataset using the same method --(datasource access on [Cluster].[dataset]) ,user is not able to see related dashboards (but there are) ,user can only see this dataset in Dataset folder.Maybe somebody knows what is the reason ?Or is this SS bug?
I am expecting -when i give access on dataset to gamma user ,user could see all related dashboards (charts) of this dataset
